# How does this levitating clock work?

Tags: hardware

I came across the Flyte STORY clock recently ([link](https://flytestore.com/pages/story-levitating-timepiece)) and I’m stumped as to how it works.
Does anyone know how it holds the ball against gravity when it’s vertically upright?

[image]

I asked Physics but they closed the question immediately. Hopefully this is the right place to ask!

[This article](https://hackaday.com/2017/02/26/howd-they-do-it-levitating-orb-clock/) touches on the subject, but provided only speculation and no detail.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is the right place to ask, either.

Comment: @auspicious99 Can you suggest a different forum?

Comment: @MichaelFinn: You can try Quora, they don't have the stringent rules of Stack Exchanges, but sometimes some questions don't get noticed.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks for the advice! I’ll leave this up in case a kind stranger feels like imparting wisdom, but no hard feelings if it needs to be closed.

Comment: Related commentary https://hackaday.com/2017/02/26/howd-they-do-it-levitating-orb-clock/

Comment: @0xec Cheers for investigating, I checked out this article prior to asking here but was frustrated by their fairly brief speculation. It surprises me that nobody is excited enough by this technology to want to know how it works!

Comment: Flyte uses [Magnetic levitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation) in other products. Hence most likely it is used here, too. There is a [thesis (German language)](https://www.tugraz.at/fileadmin/user_upload/Institute/IEP/Thermophysics_Group/Files/Teachers/Diplomarbeit_Stefan_Leitner.pdf) describing it (scroll to "Flyte" section)

Comment: it seems, this is not levitation. The systems to fetch the balls is missing in the description.
However, not what I am looking for.
Regards

Comment: @auspicious99 I think this is the right place. We don't just deal with code, but also with hardware and reverse engineering is about understanding how something "ticks". We have much fewer questions regarding [tag:hardware] than software, but still this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Briefly:**

inside the clock:
[image]

**Full manufacturing instructions:**

https://www.instructables.com/Mesmerizing-Magnetic-Wall-Clock/

[webarchived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201228064243/https://www.instructables.com/Mesmerizing-Magnetic-Wall-Clock)

Comment: Unfortunately this DIY project does not appear to levitate the ball, but rather holds it magnetically against the side of the clock face. I do appreciate the answer attempt almost three years later, though!